# JS String.replace can be tempremental with Safari

Tags: javascript, replace

The Backstory:

This works fine in all browsers EXCEPT Safari (5.0.1)

```
var chunk = arr[i];
chunk = chunk.replace('$', '\\$');
var a = eval('message.match(/' + chunk + '/gi);');
if(a instanceof Array) symbol = symbol.concat(a);
```

So I modified it to the following:

```
var chunk = String(arr[i]);
chunk = chunk.replace('$', '\\$');
var a = eval('message.match(/' + chunk + '/gi);');
if(a instanceof Array) symbol = symbol.concat(a);
```

Which made Safari a BIT more happy to where it was just throwing an ambiguous error (FUN!)

I've found the solution and I'm posting it below in case any other fellow scripters run into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the problem because I'm not sure what's the value of `chunk`.

Anyway, this is one more example of an unnecessary usage of `eval`, you can use the `RegExp` constructor to build a `RegExp` object from a string, for example:

```
var re = /foo/gi;
```

Is equivalent to creating an object in runtime with the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp('foo', 'gi');
```

Applying it to your code:

```
var chunk = String(arr[i]); // use String() only if you are not sure if arr[i] is

// Be aware that the following line is replacing only the first $ 
// char and you may want to scape other meta-characters:
chunk = chunk.replace('$', '\\$');
var a = message.match(new RegExp(chunk,'gi'));

if(a instanceof Array) symbol = symbol.concat(a);
```

Comment: +1 That struck me as weird too, but I was too lazy to get into it with him.

Answer (score 0):

So- I put a try/catch around the problem area (naturally) to try and get some sort of feedback on the error. Funny enough, I get no error and the problem goes away. Weird.

Solution:

```
try {
  var chunk = String(arr[i]);
  chunk = chunk.replace('$', '\\$');
  var a = eval('message.match(/' + chunk + '/gi);');
  if(a instanceof Array) symbol = symbol.concat(a);
} catch(e) {}
```